# Is there a minimal php5ts.dll?

Tags: php, dll, dependencies

I've completed my web app and am using mongoose to serve the php pages.  The whole app & mongoose is less then 2MB.

The php5ts.dll is almost 5MB so that really adds bloat.  Also, my app is very minimal so I don't need many of the php features, ie. mysql & crypto.

Is there a minimal php5ts.dll out there? Or can I build it from the source code without too much work?

Comment: Might have better luck on stackoverflow...

Comment: Aren't you intrested in answers, shaiss? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can recompile. Use './configure' keys (or how is it in windows, maybe, Makefile?) to add/remove functionality you need, consult the manual for the exact module directives for sets of functions.

You may Google for a pre-compiled library, but it's always better to recompile it so it meets your needs, shrinks in size and overall - fits better ;)

Also consider using packers like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/):

```
php5ts.dll: 1290 kB (62% compression)
```

(found here: [Compiling PHP with no extra weight](http://winbinder.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=204) via Googling for "UPX php5ts.dll" )

And yes, it suits StackOverflow better :)
Cheers!

Comment: I've marked this as answered as it put me on the right path.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious what's that path? Share! :)